# Edit database row using php page

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, edit

I am trying to produce a spreadsheet like page - right now ive got the information from the database being displayed and an additional page allowing the user to add information.

I cannot understand how i would call the database to display a set row. I am not running an AI id so that is out the question. I tried to implement one after but it resulted in my code not working and giving me a blank white page.

Here is the code i am using to display the database:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('', '', ''); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

//connect to the database
mysql_select_db(''); 

//query the database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ");

        echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <td class='td'>Date</td>
            <td class='td'>Region</td>
            <td class='td'>Cameraman</td>
            <td class='td'>Livestream?</td>
            <td class='td'>Event Title</td>
            <td class='td'>Lecturer</td>
            <td class='td'>Time</td>
            <td class='td'>Speaker</td>
            <td class='td'>ICE Contact</td>
            <td class='td'>Venue Address</td>
            <td class='td'>Venue Contact</td>
            <td class='td'>Additional Comments</td>
            <td class='td'>On App?</td>
            <td class='td'>Edit</td>
            <td class='td'>Delete</td>
            </tr>";

       WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
            $rows = array_filter($rows);
            if (!empty($rows)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['region'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['cameraman'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['livestream'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['eventitle'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['lecturer'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['time'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['speaker'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['icecontact'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['venueaddress'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['venuecontact'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['additionalcomments'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $rows['onapp'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a href=""><img src=""></a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href=""><img src=""></a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            endwhile;
            echo "</table>";
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was a quotes mismatch in the third last and second last line of the if block where you used **double quotes within the double quotes** which causes for syntax error. Here outer double quotes is replace with single quotes. Update the if block like this:

```
if (!empty($rows)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['region'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['cameraman'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['livestream'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['eventitle'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['lecturer'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['time'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['speaker'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['icecontact'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['venueaddress'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['venuecontact'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['additionalcomments'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $rows['onapp'] . "</td>";
                echo '<td><a href=""><img src=""></a></td>';
                echo '<td><a href=""><img src=""></a></td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
```

Comment: Ok great, I have changed that. Thanks :) My intention is to link images there that will take you to an edit page. This page will allow you to edit the row you clicked on and then update the database accordingly.

Comment: You can pass the id in a tag href and execute the mysql in the redirected page

Comment: Unfortunately i didnt set it up with ID's, when i tried to implement in phpmyadmin it broke my page. I could no long input data into the database